# How to transfer documents from iPhone to my Mac

Tags: macos, iphone, catalina, files.app

This is a beginner question.
I have some files (Photos, Documents, etc in various folders) in the Files.app in iPhone

I can connect my iPhone to my Mac using USB cable.

How do I transfer files from iPhone to my Mac using USB cable?

Comment: What have you tried already to solve the problem? Does it need to be via USB? Are the devices in the same WiFi network? Which version of macOS are you running?

Comment: @nohillside: Hi, I am running MAC Catalina OS. I tried searching in Internet but all links suggest to use some  external software. So I wanted to check here if an external software is really needed to achieve this simple thing? I feel USB cable is the best method instead of using WIFI(unnecessary internet usage and slower than USB cable), etc so I want to transfer files using the USB cable. If I want WIFI then I can use dropbox or something.

Comment: I am fine using WIFI if there is no easy way to transfer files using USB cable. Both MAC and iPhone are in same WIFI network

Comment: This may help:  https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/transfer-files-iphone-computer-iphf2d851b9/ios#:~:text=1%20Connect%20iPhone%20to%20your%20Mac.%20You%20can,of%20the%20Finder%20window%2C%20click%20...%20See%20More

Comment: Select the photos and send by message, email, iCloud etc.

Comment: @Allan: Hi Allan, I tried that already (Transfer from iPhone to Mac: Click the disclosure triangle beside an app name to see its files on your iPhone, then drag a file to a Finder window). In the Files section in MAC Finder, I do not see the `Files.app`. I see other apps like Bookshelf, Chrome, etc but not Files.app. Regarding WIFI, I tried Airdrop as well but I can only transfer files and not folders using AirDrop

Comment: FYI, incase of AirDrop(This is a WIFI solution. Not USB cable solution) I can only send files and not folders. One workaround is that I can zip/compress the Folder and then send it using AirDrop to MAC. Of course, I would need enough space in the iPhone to do this

Answer (score 1):

- See [https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/transfer-files-iphone-computer-iphf2d851b9/ios#:~:text=1%20Connect%20iPhone%20to%20your%20Mac.%20You%20can,of%20the%20Finder%20window%2C%20click%20...%20See%20More](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/transfer-files-iphone-computer-iphf2d851b9/ios#:%7E:text=1%20Connect%20iPhone%20to%20your%20Mac.%20You%20can,of%20the%20Finder%20window%2C%20click%20...%20See%20More)
- Use AirDrop
- Enable File Sharing on the Mac (System Preferences -> Sharing), take note of the name of your Mac, and then

  - open the Files app on the iPhone
  - Tap "Browse", tap the three bullets at top right, select "Connect to Server"
  - Enter the name of your Mac as `Mac Name.local, on the next screen enter your login data (from the Mac)
  - Your Mac will now be listed under "Shared" in Files app
  - Navigate to the folder you want to copy
  - Tap "Select", select the folder, tap the sharing icon on bottom left, tap "Save to Files" and navigate to your Mac there to copy the folder.

As long as both the iPhone and the Mac are in the same local WiFi network, transferring documents over WiFi won't use the Internet.

Comment: Hi, The Files.app is not listed in the Files section in MAC Finder for me

Comment: @firstpostcommenter The Files app on your iPhone :-)

Comment: On the Files app on my iPhone I have a folder which has 3 files. Now in my MAC Finder under Locations section I open the iPhone and select Files.. Here I do not see my folder/files on MAC.

Comment: @firstpostcommenter You don't need the Mac after enabling sharing there, everything else can be done within the Files app.

Comment: I am using the approach mentioned in the 1st point. Are you referring to 3rd point i.e enabling sharing? I did not try this yet. In the URL mentioned in 1st point, they mentioned that I should see my iPhone files/folders on my MAC in the Files section but I could not see them

Comment: @firstpostcommenter I can't comment on the first option, I'm not using Catalina so I can't test how it works.

Comment: ok. I am trying to use 3rd option. I enabled file sharing on MAC (tick the File sharing checkbox. I did the same as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0FvEqWaTrw). Now to test whether the server is accessible, I tried to open the smb://IPaddress on my MAC but I get error that there is problem connecting to server. I tried to connect to "Mac Name.local" from iPhone but I get an error here as well

Comment: @firstpostcommenter That's hard to analyze without further details, might be better to ask a new question for this.